# Overriding exception handling in one Symfony controller/bundle

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I have a Symfony app with five or six bundles in the src/ directory. I'd like to override Symfony's exception handling for one of the bundles, but not all. Is this possible?

I've read about overriding the error pages, but that seems to be a global thing.

Comment: What is your usecase? Can you solve it with KernelEvents::EXCEPTION?

Comment: I'm implementing peculiar API in one bundle, which specifies error handling. But I don't want the error handling to affect the other bundles at all.

Comment: As far as I understand your situation: If you're using custom exceptions for your API, then you can handle your API exceptions in an Kernelevent. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html